# How to stop backslashes being escaped when filtering with maven-resources-plugin?

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, maven-resources-plugin

I'd like to use the Maven Resources Plugin to set the XML schema location within an XML resource file:

```
<root xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="${env.myxsdpath}" ...>
```

This works except for one thing - the substituted path has double backslashes instead of a single blackslash, e.g:

```
<root xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\\mypath\\myschema.xsd" ...>
```

So two questions:

1. Is this a valid format for specifying the XSD file?
2. Is there a way to tell Maven to use a single backslash instead of double backslashes?

The environment variable `myxsdpath` is `C:\mypath\myschema.xsd`. The `maven-resources-plugin` doesn't have any special configuration other than specifying the files that are to be included with filtering turned on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behaviour is controlled by the [`escapeWindowsPaths`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#escapeWindowsPaths) attribute of the [`maven-resources-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/), introduced in version 2.4. It defaults to `true` meaning that, by default, all back-slashes will be escaped, turning single `\` into double `\\`.

> Whether to escape backslashes and colons in windows-style paths.

Sample configuration to disable this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
  <configuration>
    <escapeWindowsPaths>false</escapeWindowsPaths>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```