# Maven resources plugin: backslash being removed when filtering

Tags: java, maven

I have a problem with maven-resources-plugin. I am filtering my resources and maven is removing the backslash of my properties.

### configuration:

pom.xml

```
... 
    <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                   <includes>
                       <include>*.properties</include>
                       <include>*.html</include>
                   </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
...

    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
        <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>

...
```

development/enviroment.properties

```
...

    export.directory=\\App\\Export
    username=domain\user

...
```

environment.properties.

```
...

    export.directory=${export.directory}
    username=${username}
...
```

### Building

When I build my package (war file), with profile development, I've got a environment.properties file with simple backslashes instead of double:

```
...

    export.directory=\App\Export
    username=domainuser

...
```

maven-resources-plugin is converting my double backslashes to simple backslashes and erasing my simple backslashes.
**I need maven not to replace my backslashes.**

Comment: why not you use `export.directory=/App/Export`?

Comment: The property value \App\Export is a windows directory so must be with backslashes. It needs double backslashes because it is loaded with Java and the backslash in Java need to be scaped.

Comment: Why do you need double backslashes? In any case, if `\\` creates a single backslash, what might be used to create two backslashes? And you should only need backslashes if you're using this property outside of Java; Java doesn't care.

Comment: The '\' is a special character in Java. It is used as an escape character. You can't write \App\Export, you need to write \\App\\Export. Because of that I need to put double backslashes in my properties so Java can understand that as single backslashes.

Comment: The project was using Ant and was working ok but we are migrating to maven and the problem raised.

Comment: If the directory is a windows directory the forward slashes will work (Windows handles that correctly within the JVM)...

Comment: That's right. Forward slashes works! for paths in Windows. The problem now is that I have another properties for user names in the format: domain\user. In this case maven is deleting de backslash and I get domainuser in Java.

Comment: You mean `domain\\user` not working?

Comment: Yes. Maven is replacing domain\\user in domain\user in building time. Then the Java app converts domain\user in domainuser and calls the external service with that credentials. The service returns Unauthorized because those credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the  configuration in the `maven-resources-plugin` like explained here: [How to stop backslashes being escaped when filtering with maven-resources-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595501/how-to-stop-backslashes-being-escaped-when-filtering-with-maven-resources-plugin)

I had the problem vice versa, so that Maven always double backslashed my solo backslash in my property.